# Could I retrieve the datatype from a variable in C?

Tags: c, types

Has a way to get the datatype in C?

For example:

```
int foo;

if (foo is int)
{
    // do something
}
```

or something like:

```
if (typeof(foo) == typeof(int))
{
    // do something
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's an int, you'll know by lookint at the source code - no need for reflection !

Comment: I do not really understand the question. If you define foo as an int, why would you need to get its type at compile time afterwards; introspection is useful in object-oriented programming to implement polymorphism, but I do not see why you would need it in C.

Comment: Such constructions would be useful to implement function overloading.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is called type introspection or reflection and is not supported by the C language. You would probably have to write your own reflection library, and it would be a significant effort.

Comment: Thanks, I've already imagine that. Something like #define MY_INT and later set another variable to hold my custom type, right? Thanks.

Comment: or you could define a structure, where one field holds a "typeid" and the other field is larger enough to hold any value you might wish to store in the structure.

Answer (score 4):

There is a `typeof` extension in GCC, but it's not in ANSI C: http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuexts.html#SEC69

Comment: And it's not useful for what OP wants.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that `foo` is an `int` is bound to the name `foo`. It can never change. So how would such a test be meaningful? The only case it could be useful at all is in macros, where `foo` could expand to different-type variables or expressions. In that case, you could look at some of my past questions related to the topic:

[Type-generic programming with macros: tricks to determine type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331474/type-generic-programming-with-macros-tricks-to-determine-type)

[Determining presence of prototype with correct return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483757/determining-presence-of-prototype-with-correct-return-type)

Comment: You didn't get the point... anyway...  the question was solved by emddudley

Answer (score 1):

Since C11, you can do that with `_Generic`:

```
if (_Generic(foo, int: 1, default: 0)) // if(typeof(foo)==int)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only time you wouldn't know the type is if the type of foo is defined by a typedef -- if that's the case, your example should reflect it. And why do you need to something dependent on the type? There may well be a way to solve your actual problem, but you haven't presented your actual problem.